# Making pixel-less demo videos that look awesome

Tags: vector, adobe-after-effects

I've seen a number of awesome demo videos from Google and others that don't have any visible pixels, even when zoomed in a bunch. An example below: [image: Demo video] (from https://youtu.be/yNP5TJblkFQ?t=34s).

I'm guessing they didn't reimplement Chrome and OS X inside of Apple Motion / After Effects, but it's almost too good to be a screen recording of a Retina display laptop (especially with the clearly tweened mouse movement). Am I missing something? Thanks!

*Note:* I sent an email to Propellerhead as well, so we'll see what they say. (if they say anything)

Comment: I think this is more video related so maybe you should ask your question over here: http://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: 2nd opinion? Aww, man, already got a good answer too...

Comment: Hey Nolan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly generous to say this doesn't have any pixelation going on, but it is indeed way bigger than you could normally get.

I'm fairly sure that they used HiDPI mode.

[Original article about enabling HiDPI mode](http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2013/01/turn-on-hidpi-retina-mode-on-an-ordinary-mac.html)

**Instructions on how to enable the HiDPI mode:**

- Run this in terminal: `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true`
- Log out and Log back in
- Go to `System preferences > Displays`

  - Select ´Resolution: Scaled´ and then the (HiDPI) resolution.
- To get out of the HiDPI mode, simply switch back to your normal  resolution.

If you ever want to fully disable/hide the HiDPI option, run this in the terminal: `sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled`

---

---

**Example screenshot that I took:**

[Click to enlarge
[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0rLC.png)

Comment: Mmmm, I think that's it. Now that I look at the mouse tweens, they could have done them manually and then zoomed the video in After Effects. Thanks @joonas!